# Поиск изображений при помощи Google Custom Search API

Tags: java, kotlin, google-customsearch-api

Я делаю приложение на JavaFX и мне требуется получить озображение по поисковому запросу. Выполнять поиск в google через java можно через google-api-services-customsearch, но для поиска требуется access token и приложение в google apis.

Я создал приложение в google apis и при создании `GoogleCredential` указал идентификатор клиента(его длина 72 символа), а при создании `Customsearch.Builder` указал название приложения `appname-143932`, но после попытки выполнения запроса получаю ошибку авторизации.

```
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

Полный код(Kotlin):

```
val credential = GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token)

val customsearch = Customsearch.Builder(NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory(), credential)
                .setApplicationName(appName)
                .build()

val list = customsearch.cse().list("image name")
    list.searchType = "image"
    val search = list.execute()
    val items = search.items
    items
            .forEach {
        println(it.displayLink)
    }
```

Comment: Потому что access token надо получить, а не подсовывать туда идентификатор клиента.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja , но для этого нужно как то зайти в свою учётку, а мне нужно просто получить результаты поиска. Или токен можно получить и без авторизации?

Comment: Вот тут читайте, либо найдите библиотеку подходящую. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что для обычного поиска не трубется авторизация и получение каких либо токенов, но нужно произвести регистрацию проекта и пользовательскую систему поиска.
Ниже привед пример простого класса для поиска картинок.

```
/**
 * Класс для поиска изображений через Google Custom API
 *
 * 1) Создать проект с именем {@param projectName} на странице https://console.developers.google.com/apis/
 * 2) Включить Custom Search API и запомнить API key {@param apiKey}
 * 3) Создать пользовательский поиск https://cse.google.com/cse/all, запомнить id поисковой системы {@param cx},
 * при редактировании включить поиск изображений по умолчанию он выключен
*/
class GoogleImageSearch(val apiKey: String, val cx: String, projectName: String) {
    private val builder = Customsearch.Builder(NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory(), null)
    private val customsearch: Customsearch
    private val cse: Customsearch.Cse

    init {
        builder.applicationName = projectName
        customsearch = builder.build()
        cse = customsearch.cse()
    }

    /**
      * @param query - Поисковый запрос
      * @param imageSize - размер картинки
      * @param index - начальный индекс результатов
      * @return результаты запроса
     */
    fun search(query: String, imageSize: String = "medium", index: Long = 1): MutableList<Result>? {
        val list = cse.list(query)
        list.key = apiKey
        list.cx = cx
        list.searchType = "image"
        list.imgSize = imageSize
        list.start = index
        val search = list.execute()
        return search.items
    }
}
```